# How do carousel objects vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, carousel, vuejs3

use Vue3-carousel

there is an object of 15 elements. how to make a carousel of 5 elements correctly?

I use this template

```
<template>
<Carousel :autoplay="2000" :wrap-around="true">
<Slide v-for="slide in 10" :key="slide">
<<div class="carousel__item">{{ slide }} here I want to output an object with 5 elements</div>
</Slide>
</Carousel>
</template>

<script>
import { define Component } from 'vue'
import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue3-carousel';

import 'vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.css';

export default define Component({
name: 'Autoplay',
components: {
Carousel,
Slide,
},
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the examples ? https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/examples/

Comment: i try use this is components. tnx.